# badgeValue in UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone

In UITabBar class, there is a property called setBadgeValue to display a text in the upper right corner of the item with a surrounding red oval. I need to display a control like badgeValue in UISegmentedControl. There is no functionality like badgValue in UISegmentedControl. Please give me some ideas to do this

thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, is create a UIImageView overlay with a background similar to the badgeValue-look and add a label on top of that to show the actual value.

What you could also try is to subclass the UITabBar, and make it look like some sort of UISegmentedControl. If you want to know how to subclass UITabBar and make it look different, you could take a look at a great (open source) project called [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master).